# Merging 2 PDF in .Net

Tags: .net, pdf

I have a windows application in which I have a static PDF file(File1).
Another PDF file(File2) is created on the runtime.
I need to add the contents of the File1 to File2 as a new page of File2.
Is there a method in .Net to do this without using any external libraries or softwares.

Regards,
Abhishek Jain

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any method in .net that is capable of doing that. What we used here is abcpdf to merge/append 2 pdf.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go to all of the trouble of re-inventing the wheel, you can try [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). It's an external library, though. The .NET Framework doesn't have any built-in PDF classes.

Comment: thanx for your quick response to my query.
Can something be done with Crystal Reports.
I do not have a very clear idea of Crystal Reports.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Although I haven't used the latest version of CR.